# How to disable row selector in ALV?

Tags: abap, alv

I have a report which shows an ALV. After double clicking on a certain column, some fields in the ALV become customizable. This is done by setting the 'edit' attribute of the fieldcatalog-row for the column to 'X'.

```
<fs_field_cat_line>-edit = 'X'.
```

When I set the updated fieldcatalog, optimize its width and refresh the ALV

```
* setting fieldcatalog
lo_alv_grid->set_frontend_fieldcatalog( it_fieldcatalog = lt_field_catalog ).

* Optimizing column width
ls_layout-cwidth_opt = 'X'.
lo_alv_grid->set_frontend_layout( is_layout = ls_layout ).

* refresh ALV
lo_alv_grid->refresh_table_display( ).
```

The ALV gets get a new column at the start which can be used to select multiple rows, or when clicking at the top, select all rows.

[image: 'select all'-column]

How do I disable this Column. After refreshing, I do not want this column to appear. I have tried looking at what happens with the debugger but I can't seem to find it.

**EDIT:** After implementing the accepted solution below, the changes look like this:

```
* setting fieldcatalog
lo_alv_grid->set_frontend_fieldcatalog( it_fieldcatalog = lt_field_catalog ).

* Optimizing column width
ls_layout-cwidth_opt = 'X'.

* Disabling selection column
ls_layout-sel_mode = 'A'.
ls_layout-no_rowmark = 'X'.

* setting layout
lo_alv_grid->set_frontend_layout( is_layout = ls_layout ).

* refresh ALV
lo_alv_grid->refresh_table_display( ).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/7aca2e29728810148a4b1a83b0e91070/1511%20000/en-US/frameset.htm?4eba881e260e56a5e10000000a421937.html), you have to

- set the `NO_ROWMARK` flag of the grid to `X` **and**
- change the `SEL_MODE` setting of the grid to either `A` or `D`. The default `'  '` is interpreted as `B` which AFAIR ignores the `NO_ROWMARK` flag.